# Created function, but calling it returns returns "function not found"

Tags: r

I using R 3.6.3 in RStudio 1.2.5033.  I can't update because R is centrally managed.

For the record, I'm loading the following packages:

```
library(rugarch)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(anytime)
library(qqplotr)
```

I define a function like

```
myFunc <- function() {}
```

I then see it in my workspace.  I can even view it

```
View(myFunc)
```

But, when I execute it,

```
myFunc()
```

I get the message

> Error in myFunc() : could not find function "myFunc"

What gives?  It had been working before.

UPDATE:  I mistyped the function definition.  It is now fixed.

Comment: `function myFunc() {}` returns a syntax error in R.

Comment: I mistyped the function definition. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
myFunc <- function(x){}
myFunc(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is the problem you should define your functions as so :

```
myFunc <- function() {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The function was defined with a different name by my friend who is new to R.  It was all too easy to overlook.

Comment: If the question is entirely based on this miss definition by your friend, you should delete the question, as it is largely irrelevant to the community

Comment: SO won't let me delete it.